# Jquery responsive clickable picture slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, slideshow

I am new to JS and it has been a bear for me to learn. I am working to build a responsive site using media queries. I want a clickable slideshow that changes the main photo when you click one of the three thumbnails.

I have decided to keep the slideshow simple. I have a div with a main image and three thumbnails underneath. When I click a thumbnail I want the `mainPhoto` div class to change to a different class with a different `background-image`. I am using the jquery `.on("click",` function and `.addClass` to change the div class when one of the thumbnails are clicked. I am doing this because I am going to use media queries. If the screen is smaller or larger the div classes I am calling will have a different background image to fit the larger or smaller window. I have not added the `@media` code yet. But eventually I will have different background-images for each class depending on certain screen sizes.

Right now I just want to keep it simple and create the script that works first. My problem is that when I click the thumbnails it only works once and it only works in order meaning if I click `thumbnailThree` before `thumbnailTwo` I cannot click the others. I want to be able to click all three as money times as I want. Maybe there is an easier way to do this, but I am new to JS and jQuery. Below is my code:

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size:1.5em;
  }
  .wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 800px;
  }
  #mainDiv {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    background-color:#888;
  }
  .mainPhoto {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url(images/mainPhoto);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
  .mainPhotoTwo {
    background-image:url(images/mainPhotoTwo);
  }
  .mainPhotoThree {
    background-image:url(images/mainPhotoThree);
  }
  #secondaryDiv{
    float:left;
    width: 780px;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  #thumbOne {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0;
    background-image:url(images/thumbOne);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
  #thumbTwo {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 10px;
    padding:0;
    background-image:url(images/thumbTwo);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
  #thumbThree {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 10px;
    padding:0;
    background-image:url(images/thumbThree);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
  .clearDiv{
    clear:both;
    line-height:1px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="mainPhoto">
    </div>
    <div id="secondaryDiv">
      <h1>Title Test</h1>
      <p>A paragraph of text</p>
      <div id="thumbOne"></div>
      <div id="thumbTwo"></div>
      <div id="thumbThree"></div>
      <div class='clearDiv'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumbOne').on("click", function(){
      $('div.mainPhoto').addClass('mainPhoto');
    });
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumbTwo').on("click", function(){
      $('div.mainPhoto').addClass('mainPhotoTwo');
    });
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumbThree').on("click", function(){
      $('div.mainPhoto').addClass('mainPhotoThree');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Show it please in JSFiddle, in ordet to catch the bug faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/JQ7Rk/

The problem was .addClass kept tacking on classes to your div, instead of replacing them. Once it tacked on all three classes, .addClass stopped adding them (because they were already on!). Thus, making it so the last one was permanent!

**Edit:** Oh, I almost forgot. I didn't have your pictures, so I replaced them with cute cats.

I decided to make my changes in vanilla js

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumbOne').on("click", function(){
        var main = document.getElementById("mainPhoto");
        main.className = "mainPhoto";
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumbTwo').on("click", function(){
        var main = document.getElementById("mainPhoto");
        main.className = "mainPhoto mainPhotoTwo";
    });
 });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumbThree').on("click", function(){
        var main = document.getElementById("mainPhoto");
        main.className = "mainPhoto mainPhotoThree";
    });
  });
```